# odoo 8: Import ir.translation with External ID

Tags: import, odoo, translation, odoo-8

I have successfully imported several product templates into Odoo (version  8) and used External IDs for this. Now I want to import product description translations into ir.translation and want to use these External IDs. I guess, I have to put in field "Record ID" a reference to the product template - but this field unfortunately doesn't support External IDs in import screen.

How can I import translations for product templates with external IDs in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you well (you want to translate the field `description` of a `product.template` record which was introduced by XML code in a module you did before), you can try this and tell me if it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data noupdate="0">
        <record id="whatever_you_want" model="ir.translation">
            <field name="name">product.template,description</field>
            <field name="type">model</field>
            <field name="res_id" ref="the_module_which_introduced_xml_records.the_xml_id_of_the_record_you_want_to_translate"/>
            <field name="lang">de_DE</field> <!-- The code of the language you want to translate to -->
            <field name="src">Your product template description</field>
            <field name="value">Your translation (in this case to German)</field>
        </record>
    </data>
</openerp>
```